# Как сделать эффект заполнения при фокусе на инпут

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет.

Надо сделать такой эффект *пополнения инпута черным цветом* точно так же как [**тут**](http://www.erminandoaliaj.com/contact)

Я пробовал изменить задний фон при `focus`-е и задать плавность (`transition:background 0.5s ease-in-out`) но получилсья так что он проста плавно появляетсья и изчезает.

Скрипты написанные на **TweenMax** приветствуютсья

Ссылка на [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/jpMvBd)

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}
form .form-group:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4.6%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
form .form-group:nth-child(3) {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 4.8%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
form .form-group input {
  border-right-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.67;
  line-height: 2.5;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-width: thin;
}
form .form-group input:focus {
  background-color: black;
}
form .form-group textarea {
  resize: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.67;
  font-family: 'Mongolian Baiti';
  margin-top: 50px;
}
form .form-group .name {
  width: 100%;
}
form .text-center button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #14bed7;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3.1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

form .form-group .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder, form .form-group .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder, form .form-group .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Mongolian Baiti';
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #102a2a;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form">
   <form id="contact-form"  action="#" method="POST" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="name"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1" required>
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="email"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="email" class="form-control email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2" required>
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="phone"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control phone" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3">
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="message"></label>
       <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..." tabindex="4" required></textarea>                                 
     </div>
     <div class="text-center">
       <button type="submit" class="btn start-order">Send</button>
     </div>
   </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загляните в панель разработчика на сайт с которого берете пример:

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}
form .form-group:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4.6%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
form .form-group:nth-child(3) {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 4.8%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
form .form-group input {
  border-right-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.67;
  line-height: 2.5;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-width: thin;
}
form .form-group input:focus {
  background-color: black;
}
form .form-group textarea {
  resize: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.67;
  font-family: 'Mongolian Baiti';
}
form .form-group .name {
  width: 100%;
}
form .text-center button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #14bed7;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3.1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

form .form-group .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder, form .form-group .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder, form .form-group .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Mongolian Baiti';
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #102a2a;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-group__txt {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

textarea + span,
input + span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

input:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
}


textarea:focus + span,
input:focus + span {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form">
   <form id="contact-form"  action="#" method="POST" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="name"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1" required>
       <span></span>
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="email"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="email" class="form-control email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2" required>
       <span></span>
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="phone"></label>
       <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control phone" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3">
       <span></span>
     </div>                            
     <div class="form-group form-group__txt">
       <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..." tabindex="4" required></textarea> 
       <span></span>
     </div>
     <div class="text-center">
       <button type="submit" class="btn start-order">Send</button>
     </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: спасибо но там я не нашел ничего и пример не от туда был.плюсик за ответ